# How can I templatize a function without repeating code but only changing the parsing function?

Tags: c++, templates

I have an existing function that converts a comma-delimited string of numbers into a vector, e.g. "1,2,3" becomes [1,2,3]

The function looks very roughly like:

```
bool ConvertStringToNumberList(string input, vector<int32_t>& output)
{
  <bunch of code>
  int32_t value = strtol(str, 0, /*base*/ 10);
  <bunch of code>
}
```

I would like to change this into a template function that will work for int32_t, uint32_t, double, and float.

The problem is that, for each data type, there is a different parsing function (e.g. strtol, strtoul, strtod, strtof) that may take different number of parameters (e.g. strtod() does not take a "base" parameter).

How can I templatize the above code without repeating the `<bunch of code>` but only changing the parsing function?

Comment: You can always use `std::stringstream` which already provides overloads of `operator>>` for the types listed in your post. Then just do something like `ssinput >> value;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create the class which will have specializations, each with a static function to parse one of the types you want to support and use it from your function template.

E.g.:

```
template <typename T>
struct Converter {};

template <>
struct Converter<int32_t> {
   static int32_t Parse(const std::string& str) {
      return strtol(str, 0, /*base*/ 10); 
   }
};

template <>
struct Converter<double> {
   static double Parse(const std::string& str) {
      return atof(str); 
   }
};

template <typename T>
bool ConvertStringToNumberList(string input, vector<T>& output) {
  // <bunch of code>
  T value = Converter<T>::Parse(str);
  // <bunch of code>
}
```

Alternatively, you may have plain `Parse` function, which has overloads for each type,
but there you may get unexpected type promotions.

Comment: Making this the accepted answer because it's most in line with what I was looking for (the proper template magic).  But the other answers are very good alternatives to the whole problem.

Comment: Glad it helped you and thanks for the correction. Functions need obviously be static.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you really want to do the whole job yourself, you're probably best off using something other than `strtol` to start with. One possibility that would fit pretty nicely here would be `boost::lexical_cast`:

```
template <class T>
ConvertStringToNumberList(string input, vector<T> &output) { 
    <bunch of code>
    T value = boost::lexical_cast<T>(str);
    <bunch more code>
}
```

`lexical_cast` is pretty much equivalent to stuffing the string into a stringstream, then reading out the specified type, but it provide overloads to optimize for many of the most common types, so in many (most?) typical cases, it's quite a bit faster.

Comment: Interesting idea.  Part of the problem is that the '<bunch of code>' is partly error handling, e.g. "1,garbage,3" or ",,," would return false.  I'll have to see if lexical_cast will throw bad_lexical_cast in all the right cases.  If so, this will be shorter than implementing Krizz' solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom delimeters for stream extraction by setting their mask table value to `std::ctype_base::space`, use that table to create a facet, create a locale using the facet, imbue that locale on a stream and use `operator>>` or `std::istream_iterator` to extract your stuff.

You'll need some headers...

```
#include <vector>
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstring>
```

The facet could look like this:

```
class custom_delimter_facet : public std::ctype<char>
{
public:
  static custom_delimter_facet * new_facet(std::string const &delimeters)
  {
    std::ctype<char>::mask * mask_table 
      = new std::ctype<char>::mask[std::ctype<char>::table_size];
    // Set zero
    std::memset(mask_table, 0, 
            sizeof(std::ctype<char>::mask)*std::ctype<char>::table_size);
    // Set delimeters
    for (auto delim : delimeters)
      mask_table[delim] = std::ctype_base::space;
    // create facet with table
    return new custom_delimter_facet(mask_table);
  }
  custom_delimter_facet(std::ctype<char>::mask const * tbl)
    : std::ctype<char>(tbl, false), m_facet_mask(tbl)
  { }
  ~custom_delimter_facet()
  {
    if (m_facet_mask) delete[] m_facet_mask;
  }
private:
  std::ctype<char>::mask const * m_facet_mask;
};
```

It can be used to have a single, tempalted function creating a vector of elements with this facet:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> vec_from_string(std::string const &string, 
  std::string const & delimeters = " \n")
{
  // Create input stringstream
  std::istringstream siss(string);
  // Imbue custom delimeted locale
  // facet will be deleted by locale destructor
  siss.imbue(std::locale(siss.getloc(), 
    custom_delimter_facet::new_facet(delimeters)));
  // Fill vector
  std::vector<T> data;
  std::copy(std::istream_iterator<T>(siss),
    std::istream_iterator<T>(),
    std::back_inserter(data));
  // return vector
  return data;
}
```

A small test:

```
int main()
{ 
  std::string test1("1423::1232:545367:123231;123454;353456:524;24234");
  std::string test2("17,23,55,44,63,57,0");
  std::string test3("13.4472 , 29.2247 , 44.600");

  std::vector<size_t> result1 = vec_from_string<size_t>(test1, ":;\n");
  std::vector<size_t> result2 = vec_from_string<size_t>(test2, " ,\n");
  std::vector<double> result3 = vec_from_string<double>(test3, " ,\n");

  std::cout << "Result 1 size: " << result1.size() << "\n";
  std::cout << "Result 2 size: " << result2.size() << "\n";
  std::cout << "Result 3 size: " << result3.size() << "\n";

  for (auto const & item : result1)
  {
    std::cout << "Res1 item: " << item << "\n";
  }
  for (auto const & item : result2)
  {
    std::cout << "Res2 item: " << item << "\n";
  }
  for (auto const & item : result3)
  {
    std::cout << "Res3 item: " << item << "\n";
  }
}
```

The result i expect is:

```
Result 1 size: 8
Result 2 size: 7
Result 3 size: 3
Res1 item: 1423
Res1 item: 1232
Res1 item: 545367
Res1 item: 123231
Res1 item: 123454
Res1 item: 353456
Res1 item: 524
Res1 item: 24234
Res2 item: 17
Res2 item: 23
Res2 item: 55
Res2 item: 44
Res2 item: 63
Res2 item: 57
Res2 item: 0
Res3 item: 13.4472
Res3 item: 29.2247
Res3 item: 44.6
```

Comment: Wow, complex :)  I give you points for probably being most in line with C++ stream methodology.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `boost:lexical_cast` you have the option of using `std::istringstream`. This will give you the choice of having failed conversions either return an error or throw an exception. Just like `boost:lexical_cast` the amount of code required to work this into your existing code is minimal and does not require any additional functions or overloads to handle the actual conversion.

In the example below the success of the conversion can be determined by checking the return type of `operator>>`. By default string streams return an error instead of throwing an exception so no additional code should be required. This will should fit quite with your existing code.

```
template<class ValueType>
bool ConvertStringToNumberList(string input, vector<ValueType>& output)
{
    // <bunch of code>

    ValueType value;
    if (!(istringstream(input) >> value))
    {
        //  Conversion faild
        return false;
    }

    // <bunch of code>
    return true;
}
```

The example below specifies exceptions be thrown when the conversion fails. In this case I don't think exceptions will be needed unless the data is expected to be correct.

```
template<class ValueType>
bool ConvertStringToNumberList2(string input, vector<ValueType>& output)
{
    // <bunch of code>

    ValueType value;
    istringstream stream(input);
    stream.exceptions(istringstream::failbit);
    stream >> value;

    // <bunch of code>
    return true;
}
```

Both examples pass the context of `input` to the string stream to make it easier for you to test. Just change `input` to whatever variable holds the text extracted from the input string.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could check the return value of istream operations. FYI (I didn't know this until investigating your answer) that the !(istringstream(input) >> value) works because the ios class (base class of istream) overrides operator!() to return true if the failbit or badbit is set.  I.e. it's not checking the return value of operator>>() directly, which is an istream&.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to templatising your function create a new function which will take care of the line of code

```
int32_t value = strtol(str, 0, /*base*/ 10);
```

This function does not need to be a template - just use overloading and create appropriate conversion function overload for each of the data types you need. Then call the overloaded function from your template - the function specific to the type will be selected automatically.